# Restored from iCloud - asking for old friends account constantly

Tags: itunes, icloud, restore, authorization

I just got a new phone, and I restored from my previous phone's iCloud backup, which worked great EXCEPT I apparently had one or two songs in my music that were authorized by an old friend of mine. It keeps asking me now for that friends Apple password to authorize the song - but I have no idea what song it is. I would really just like to get rid of the song, but how can I go about finding it?

Answer (score 1):

[This article](https://www.macworld.com/article/3255627/entertainment/how-to-find-out-who-purchased-a-song-from-itunes-store.html) from Macworld.com last week addressed this issue. I enclose a link, as the technique is too long to describe...and I haven't tried it.